# In Laravel database can I use a previously made array of conditions in where function?

Tags: mysql, laravel, rdbms

In laravel tutorial it's said that we can pass an array of conditions in where function. My question is when I pass an array of conditions previously made by me it doesn't work.

Here is the code in documentation:

```
$users = DB::table('users')->where([
['status', '=', '1'],
['subscribed', '<>', '1'],
])->get();
```

My code is:

```
$fields = collect($request->input());
    if($fields->has('data')){
        $fields = collect($fields->get('data'));
        $conditions = collect([]);
        if($fields->has('likes')){
            $fieldsL = $fields->get('likes');
            $conditions->push(['likes', $fieldsL]);
        }
        if($fields->has('title')){
            $fieldsT = $fields->get('title');
            $conditions->push(['title', $fieldsT]);
        }
        $data = DB::table('posts')->select('*')->where($conditions)-

>get();
        }
```

My error message:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '[]' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `posts` where `[]` is null) in file D:\laravel\lara-api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php on line 68
```

PLEASE let me know if it's impossible.
thanks.

Comment: @TimLewis I added the error message

Comment: Much better :) To answer your question, it _is_ possible, but there's something wrong with `$conditions` as you're constructing it. Can you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67926094/edit) and add the output of `dd($conditions)`?

Comment: @TimLewis If I use
return dd($conditions); in controller then I get
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1196
  #items: []
}

Comment: That means you're passing an empty `Collection` to `->where()`, and that doesn't work. `Model::where(collect([]))->first()` throws that error. If you do `->where($conditions->toArray())`, it won't throw an error, and will return everything. Apparently, `where()` doesn't seem to like `Collection`s.

Comment: @ArifurRahmanArif It's better to use laravel eloquent for collect your posts. Would you like to use that?

Comment: @MohammadHosseini That's irrelevant to this post. `DB::table('posts')->where($conditions)` and `Post::where($conditions)` would have the same issue here.

Comment: @TimLewis Thanks. It works

Comment: @TimLewis Is there a better way to do the work? Please let me know

Comment: This approach is fine, you just need to be aware of the difference between a `Collection` and an `array`. Alternatively, you could do `$query = DB::table('posts')->query();`, then in your `if()` statements, do `$query = $query->where(...);`, then at the end `$data = $query->get();`.